# How to know the store/shop name from address in android apps?

Tags: android, android-location

I am new to android app development. My app needs to know the store name when a user enters in a store. I can find the co-ordinates using LocationManager and then the address of the place using the Geocoder. But how do I find out which store it is, based on the information above? Or is there any other way to get the store name using Google Maps API or Google Places etc.?

Comment: Google Places API gives detailed information about the place; not only things like name, but if they are open, what type of place it is, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting business names or landmarks from lat/long in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102299/getting-business-names-or-landmarks-from-lat-long-in-android)